# How to assign passed value to a final field in constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Code:**

```
class MyColor {
  final Color one;
  final Color two;

  MyColor({
    this.one = Colors.black,
    this.two = one.withOpacity(0.5), // error
  });
}
```

Is there any way to assign the value of `one` to `two` in the constructor itself, I want all fields to be `final`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
class MyColor {
  final Color one;
  final Color two;

  MyColor({
    this.one = Colors.black,
    Color? two,
  }) : two = two ?? one.withOpacity(0.5);
}
```